# Appends / Upload data into binary columns in chunk

Tags: php, laravel, memory, memory-management, eloquent

I could not find any resource to solve this issue

I have a binary column in laravel model defined like this

```
binary('data')
```

I would like to store very large data above 1GB into a binary column in small chunks, that means appending those chunks to the existing data.

which means

```
model->data =  model->data + chunk;
```

How can I achieve that in a very memory efficient way without uploading the previous content into RAM which may trigger out of RAM error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this query :

```
    Model::update([
        'data' => DB::raw("data + $chunk"),
    ]);

    or

    DB::table('your_table_name')->update([
        'data' => DB::raw("data + $chunk"),
    ]);
```

**remember: define your condition for update**